# Adding an image to text widget of Tkinter in python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am new to Tkinter and i am trying to add an image to a text widget in Tkinter python 2.7
I have looked up some resources on the internet and as far as i have gotten is this code but it is giving error - 
 "

```
File "anim.py", line 11, in <module>
    text.image_create(END,image=photoImg)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2976, in image_create
    *self._options(cnf, kw))
  TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type file)
```

"

please tell me where i went wrong. Thanks in advance :)

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x900+100+100")
image1 = open('IMG_20160123_170503.jpg')
photoImg = PhotoImage(image1)
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
text = Text(frame)
text.pack()
text.image_create(END,image=photoImg)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Text widget obviously does not support images. I recently needed pictures  in a text widget. I used a canvas, put a frame on it and packed smaller frames on it as "lines" and inside these I added labels with text, and images. You can find everything how to do. Search for scrollable widgets on a canvas, images on labels and implement it to your code.

Comment: @Vivekkumarpathak I think people have hastily downvoted here. The Tkinter Text widget **does** support embedded images.

Comment: @JozefMéry: you are incorrect. The text widget _does_ support embedded images.  This is a well documented feature that has been in tkinter since the very beginning ot Tkinter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have made just two small mistakes. When you `open` the image as `image1` you are using Python's built-in `open` keyword rather than `Image.open`, the method of PIL's `Image` class. You also reference Tkinter's `PhotoImage` class when you mean to reference PIL's `ImageTk.PhotoImage` class. Here is your fixed code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
root = Tk()
root.geometry("900x900+100+100")
image1 = Image.open("IMG_20160123_170503.jpg")
photoImg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
text = Text(frame)
text.pack()
text.image_create(END,image=photoImg)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank You so much it really helped :)